# How to hand polish gummies?

Tags: candy

I would like some advice on how to hand polish a batch of gummies. I have MCT & Grapeseed oil and carnauba wax.
I can emulsify the carnauba wax together with the oils by heating them together. Now my question is how can I hand polish my batch of gummies? It's a small batch (60), and I don't have a coating pan or tumbler.

Comment: Do you have any other devices that might work as a tumbler?  I wonder if a salad spinner might work, or maybe some large container with a lid that you could seal and shake.  (But I’ve never made gummies, so I’m just guessing based on what I’ve seen from tv shows about making candies)

Comment: Your question is more how can you avoid hand polishing gummies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're determined to hand-polish them, I'd recommend settling the dehydrated gummies on a wire-rack over a baking sheet, then using a silicone brush to coat one side. Once dry, flip the gummies and do it again, coating the uncovered side.

The downside to doing it this way is that you'll leave double the "foot" of thicker coating on the gummies where the wax-solution drips off towards the bottom, so think about the placement in relation to the shape of your gummy.

If you're looking to emulate a tumbler, I would suggest using a sealed plastic container (Tupperware, an old takeaway container, etc.), adding your gummies and your solution and shaking the tumbler until it looks like the coating is evenly applied. At this point, you can leave them on a wire rack to dry.

You can do multiple coats, so personally I would err on the side of thinning the wax-solution, and using too-little coating multiple times over too-thick a coating once.